# Почему не получаю пост запрос в servlet используя $.ajax?

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, ajax, servlet

Не могу разобраться почему POST запрос не попадает в сервлет по URL. Может что-то с AJAX намудрил?

```js
function validate(event) {


        if(document.getElementById("inputPassword").value !== document.getElementById("inputPasswordConfirm").value) {
            alert("Passwords are different!!!")
            event.preventDefault();
        } else {
            var data = {
                login: document.getElementById("field1").value,
                name: document.getElementById("field2").value,
                surname: document.getElementById("field3").value,
                email: document.getElementById("field4").value,
                icq: document.getElementById("field5").value,
                gender: document.getElementById("name").value,
                password: document.getElementById("inputPassword")
            };alert(data);
            $.ajax({

                type: 'POST',
                url: '/newuserprocessing',
                data: data,

                success: function (data) {
                    alert(data);
                },
                error: function (data) {
                    alert(data);
                }
            });
        }


    }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <script src="http://bootstraptema.ru/plugins/jquery/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://bootstraptema.ru/plugins/2015/b-v3-3-6/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://bootstraptema.ru/plugins/2016/validator/validator.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <hr>
  <form onsubmit="validate(event)"> <!-- data-toggle="validator" role="form"-->

    <div class="form-row">

      <div class="col">
        <input id="field1" type="text" class="form-control" pattern="[а-яА-Яa-zA-Z0-9_-]{4,12}" autofocus required title="Введите от 4 до 12 символов" placeholder="Введите логин">
      </div>

    </div>

    <div class="form-row">
      <div class="col">
        <input id="field2" type="text" class="form-control" pattern="[A-Za-zА-Яа-яЁё]+" autofocus placeholder="Введите Ваше имя" required>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-row">
      <div class="col">
        <input id="field3" type="text" class="form-control" pattern="[A-Za-zА-Яа-яЁё]+" autofocus placeholder="Введите Вашу фамилию" required>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-row">
      <div class="col">
        <input id="field4" type="text" class="form-control" required autofocus pattern="^[-a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~]+(?:\.[-a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9]([-a-z0-9]{0,61}[a-z0-9])?)*[\.]{1}(?:aero|arpa|asia|biz|cat|com|coop|edu|gov|info|int|jobs|mil|mobi|museum|name|net|org|pro|tel|travel|[a-z][a-z])$" placeholder="Введите Ваш e-mail">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-row">
      <div class="col">
        <input id="field5" type="text" class="form-control" pattern="^([0-9]-?){7,8}[0-9]$" autofocus required title="Введите ICQ номер, формата: xxx-xxx-xxx или xxx-xxx-xx или xx-xxx-xxx или xxxxxxxxx" placeholder="Введите ваш ICQ">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-row">
      <label for="name">Выберите ваш пол:</label>
      <select id="name" class="form-control">
        <option>Мужской</option>
        <option>Женский</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">

      <label for="inputPassword" class="control-label">Введите пароль</label>
      <div class="form-inline row">
        <div class="form-group col-sm-6"> <!-- "/^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[^\w\s]).{6,}?/"  data-toggle="validator" -->
          <input type="password" data-minlength="6" data-toggle="validator" class="form-control" id="inputPassword" placeholder="123456"
                 pattern="^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)[a-zA-Z\d]{6,}$" autofocus required title="Введите пароль от 6 до 12 символов. Пароль должен содержать обязательно большие и маленькие буквы, цифры. Допустимы а так же символы: ?=.*-" >
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-sm-6">
          <input type="password" class="form-control" id="inputPasswordConfirm" data-match="#inputPassword" data-match-error="Ошибка! Пароли не совпадают!" placeholder="Повторите пароль" autofocus required
                 title="Пароли должны совпадать!" pattern="^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)[a-zA-Z\d]{6,}$" >
          <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="checkbox">
        <label>
          <input type="checkbox" id="terms">
          Подписаться на рассылку
        </label>
        <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <input type="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Зарегистрироваться">
  </form>
```

JavaServlet:

```
@WebServlet("/newuserprocessing")
public class RegistrationServlet extends HttpServlet{
    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        System.out.println(req.getParameter("data"));
        resp.getWriter().print("Welcome, you are in servlet!");
    }

    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
    System.out.print("Ты в Пост запросе");


    }
}
```

Comment: В логах клиента что?

Comment: @Suvitruf прошу прощения, о каких логах речь?

Comment: Клиентских. Вы посылаете запрос, что сервер возвращает? 404? 500?

Comment: @Suvitru Консоль молчит. 
Страница остается без изменений пару-секунд, потом перезагружается и все заполненные поля (это страница регистрации) обнуляются.

Comment: В сервлет пост не попадает. Даже вывод на консоль о том, что "ты зашёл в пост-запрос" не отрабатывается

Comment: Вызывайте `event.preventDefault();` первой строчкой в `validate` без всяких условий. У Вас сейчас происходит стандартный сабмит формы, поэтому обработчики `success`/`error` не вызываются.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ответ пользователя @ThunderCat из портала "Тостер" на мой вопрос:
- у вас скрипты падают, проверьте что у вас вызывает ошибку, скорее всего password: document.getElementById("inputPassword").value
- аяксовых запросов в нетворке нет, значит до вызова аякс запроса скрипт не доходит.
- используйте console.log() для отладки, он более информативен.